# How to update column with data from another table? - SQL Server 12.0.5

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update the column "efficiency" in the table "SUS_WK" with the data from the column "custom_number_8" from the table "SC_PROD". But I only want it to update if certain requirements are met, such as the "ID" from table "SUS_WK" matches the "ID" from the table "SC_PROD".

How can I do this?

I have tried to do this:

```
    UPDATE SUS_WK
    SET efficiency = SC_PROD.custom_number_8
    FROM SUS_WK t
        JOIN SC_PROD p
        ON t.id = p.id
```

When I tried the code above, I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "SC_PROD_PLAN_PLND.custom_number_8" could not be bound.

But I expect the result of that code to update the column "efficiency" in the "SUS_WK" with the data from column "custom_number_8" in the table "SC_PROD".

Comment: You're real close. You just need to turn the part after the equal sign into a proper select statement. I think you also need to wrap it in parens as well.

Comment: Your *tag* says SQL Server **2012** but the title seems to indicate **v12.0.5** - this however would be SQL Server **2014** (2012 is v11.x.x) .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Just use the table alias rather than the table name:

```
UPDATE t
    SET efficiency = p.custom_number_8
    FROM SUS_WK t JOIN
          SC_PROD p
          ON t.id = p.id;
```

I strongly recommend using the table alias for the `UPDATE` as well.  SQL Server will resolve the table name to be the same as the `t` -- but depending on that makes the query rather hard to decipher (because references to the same table have difference aliases).

Comment: hehe looks like your keyboard speed is extra fast today. :)

Comment: @SeanLange, he typed this answer yesterday. He was just waiting for Mark to pose the question.